# AutoCompleteDecorate implemented on JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox, swingx

For those who are familiar with SwingX's `AutoCompleteDecorator`, I have a question regarding handling of `JComboBox`'s Popup Visibility. I used `AutoCompleteDecorate.decorate(JComboBox combobox)` in my current project which I already mentioned in my previous posts, the problem I encountered is when ever the user type a keyword that doesn't match any of the combobox items, the popup remains visible. For the convenience of the users, I would like to hide combobox's popup if the keyword typed doesn't match any of combobox items.

Comment: swingx tag added. Hopefully this will attract Kleopatra to your question.

Comment: @Hovercraft attracted :-) No answer, though: that's not supported (assuming you want to hide the popup), and I'm not sure that it should - could be a confusing user experience if the popup hides/shows seemingly without reason ...

Comment: _@kleopatra thank you for letting yourself "attracted" to my question :) Anyway is ti possible to override the Popup visibility?_

Comment: _I am finding someway to implement automatic hide of combobox's popup if noting in the combobox list macthes the typed keyword on it._

Answer (score 1):

If you want the autocompletion feature, but you don't want to have a popup in the way (especially, as you mention, when entered text doesn't match any item) you might like to try the opensource [JIDE Common Layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm). It has a very useful (I use it a lot myself) autocompletion feature that you can apply to `JComboBox`es, `JTextField`s, etc..

You can see a Java Web Start overview of the components by clicking on the "RUN IT" link on the above page, or by clicking [here](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/1.4/jide_demo.jnlp). Navigate to

```
Demos->AutoCompletion Demo->AutoCompletion combo box and text field->AutoCompletion JTextField with a hidden data
```

to try it out. You can also see the source code by clicking on *Browse Source Code*.

You can enable/disable a *strict* flag in order to prevent/allow user to enter text not matched with items.

However, as far as I have tested, JIDE's combo boxes with autocompletion also have the "issue" that keep their popup open even if no match is found, but what I'm suggesting here is to try an autocompleting textfield which has no popup at all (they autocomplete in place, highlighting the part of the matched text that you didn't manually type-in).